# Laravel Model getting only one related model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I got a User Model which is related to working terms which is related to services like that:

```
 users      working_terms    services
 id    ->    user_id
             service_id  <-    id 
            active(1 or 0)
```

I made a method in my User model in order to retrieve the service of the active working term like that

```
public function service()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany(Service::class,'working_terms')
            ->where('active','=',1);

    }
```

The problem is that I must use it like that in views $user->service[0] it should be in my opinion $user->service.
What can I do?

Comment: you need to take a look this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: I just want ONE record based on a boolean criteria not an array

Comment: If there's no way a user can be associated with more than one service (e.g. by adding another row in the pivot with the same user_id but a different service_id) then you need to review your database design and make the user-service realtionship one-to-many or one-to-one

Comment: One user can have during time multiple working terms but only one is active, and each working terms has one service, I don't think that it's database design problem. working_terms is in fact a pivot table

Answer (score 0):

When Laravel evaluates `$user->service`, first it determines if return value of `$user->service()` is a instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relation\Relation` class and if not, then it gives you error. Your `service()` method returns `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` instead of `Relation`, so that's why your snippet `$user->service` doesn't return the service model you want.

For more details, see this link; https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L432

Answer (score 0):

The `belongsToMany` relationship returns an `Eloquent Collection` regardless of whether you provide a `where` clause as part of the relationship. Therefore you will want to use `first()` to obtain the first (and only?) record.

On a side note Laravel has a naming convention for pivot tables (albeit I am sure you have your reasons for choosing the names you have).

**User.php**

```
public function services()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Service::class)
              ->withTimestamps();
}

public function getActiveServiceAttribute()
{
  return $this->services()
              ->wherePivot('active', 1)
              ->first();
}
```

The above makes the assumption I am following Laravel naming conventions where the pivot table between the `users` and `services` tables is named `service_user`.

**create_service_user_table.php**

```
public function up()
{
  Schema::create('service_user', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreignId('user_id');
    $table->foreignId('service_id');
    $table->unsignedTinyInteger('active')->default(0);

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->foreign('service_id')->references('id')->on('services');
  });
}
```

As you're not following Laravel naming conventions, you'll need to provide the name of your pivot table as the second argument to the `belongsToMany` relationship in the `services()` function (or if possible change the pivot table name and follow conventions).

You should now be able to do things like:

```
// obtain a collection of all services the User has been associated with
User::find(1)->services

// obtain the currently active service for the User
User::find(1)->activeService
```